# Can I delete unattached media via xmlrpc?

Tags: wordpress, xml-rpc

Easy question for you guys and girls.

Can I delete unattached media via xmlrpc? If so please guide me to what function will do it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely you can, you use `wp.deletePost` with post_id as param, and you make post_id the id of your attached or unattached media.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly. Delete functions are locked to 'page' and 'post' post_type-s. Only [the rFC Plugin](http://www.wpremotecontrol.com/) can help you. It exposes all WordPress functions to XMLRPC clients. Or write your own XMLRPC extension. Nevertheless, you need to PIMP WP to do this remotely.

Comment: Now you can since WordPress 3.4